# issue with scaling EC2 Volume (Make it smaller) in EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to resize the size of one of my servers, 
currently it's 850GB and i would like to scale it down to 100GB.

scaling them up isn't a problem, i just follow the basic scheme of

1. shutting down the server
2. detaching the volume
3. Creating snapshot
4. Creating new volume and attaching it to the same zone.

the problem is that i cannot create a smaller volume based on that snapshot, anyone has any idea on how to do it ?

the OS is ubuntu (if it matters)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this isn't a boot volume, your best bet is probably just to attach a new EBS volume, copy everything over, then detach the old larger volume.

Comment: Actually it is, that's the issue.